# HTACCESS / ErrorDocument - How to serve 410 instead of 403

Tags: htaccess

Can anyone please tell me how to server 410 instead of 403 (without serving any html page in 403)?

Like instead of:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

we need something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403:410 #/i.e. 403 will show default browser's 410/Gone error
```